# More Pythonic Context Manager Wrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, context-manager

I wanted to ask this here because what I wanted to originally do felt like a really Pythonic method. I want to be able to use the syntax:

```
d = {'apple':{'cranberry':{'banana':{'chocolate':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}}},'b':2}
with d['apple']['cranberry']['banana']['chocolate'] as item:
    for i in item:
        print(i)

    item.append('k')
```

but found that Python doesn't allow for using lists, dicts, etc. as context managers.

So I implemented my own:

```
def context_wrap(target):
    class ContextWrap:
        def __init__(self, tgt):
            self._tgt = tgt

        def __enter__(self):
            return self._tgt

        def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
            pass

    return ContextWrap(target)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with context_wrap({'a':1}) as item:
        print(item['a'])

    with context_wrap([1,2,3,4,5]) as item:
        print(item[1])

    with context_wrap(3) as item:
        print (item)
```

In the above code, you can take any random object and wrap it inside an object that acts as a context manager controlling the underlying object. This means that inside any `with` clause, you can simply use the object with its alias. I feel like it looks a lot cleaner and clearer than something like:

```
alias = d['apple']['cranberry']['banana']['chocolate']
for i in alias:
    print(i)

alias.append('k')
```

I wanted to know if there was a more "Pythonic" way to do it. So the improvement that I'm looking for is in terms of better reliance on the standard Python library and/or in terms of my syntax.

Comment: What's the advantage of this over just saying `item = d['a']`?  Usually the purpose of a context manager is to do something in the `__exit__` (close a file, free a resource, etc) but your use case doesn't require anything like that.

Comment: Welcome to code review, the question might be better received if the title was something like `Context Manager Wrapper` and there was a paragraph explaining what the code does.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Let me amend my post.

Comment: @SamStafford This is going to be used for more complicated objects where you wouldn't want to just endlessly list the same parameters over and over.
Something like `d = {'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':'e'}}}}` where the object is complex/deeply nested.

Comment: You might want to read the guidelines for good questions at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are doing is crazy, but yes, you can use Python’s library functions to clean it up.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def context_wrap(target):
    yield target
```

Again, this is busy work.

```
alias = thing
```

is clearer, shorter and faster than

```
with context_wrap(thing) as alias:
```

Comment: Wow, this is extremely much cleaner than my solution. And I can see a few uses for it! Using a context manager doesn't leave a strong reference around in case something needs to be cleaned up by the garbage collector! I think it's especially useful for classes.

Comment: `alias` will still be equal to `thing` after the `with` statement exits.  It doesn't remove the variable, so a strong reference will still exist!

Comment: I think I have some more work to do then. But thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Trying to trick the Python garbage collector into cleaning things up at specific times is not going to be a fun game to play.  Write it in Rust if object lifetimes are that important!  :)

Answer (score 4):

AJNeufeld provides the proper way to create small context managers using `contextlib.contextmanager`. While this is, for sure, the best way to accomplish your goal, I wanted to comment on the general use case of functions like the following:

```py
def context_wrap(target):
    class ContextWrap:
        def __init__(self, tgt):
            self._tgt = tgt

        def __enter__(self):
            return self._tgt

        def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
            pass

    return ContextWrap(target)
```

With this sort of function, you are creating the class, instantiating it, and then throwing away the class definition on each function call. All this needs to be is the class definition, and then use that directly:

```py
class ContextWrap:
    def __init__(self, tgt):
        self._tgt = tgt

    def __enter__(self):
        return self._tgt

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass


with ContextWrap(target) as cw:
    # do something
```

Which is much lighter since you aren't re-creating resources all the time.

Any time you find yourself using that pattern, go simpler.